# Poor fit with nlinfit

Tags: matlab

I'm having fitting issues with nlinfit. I can't seem to figure out how to improve the fit. Decreasing TolX or TolFun has not changed the value in coeffs.

```
 model = @(a,x) 1./(1 + a*x.^2); 
 model0 = [1e13];  
 opts = statset('TolX', 1e-25, 'TolFun', 1e-25); 
 coeffs = nlinfit(freqData, noiseData, model, model0, opts);
```

Here's my fit. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOi5o.png

Comment: Is it possible to scale, or normalize, your data so that the magnitude of each element is close to one? You could then "de-normalize" after fitting if you saved the scaling factor.

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you are dealing with very small numbers so there might be a floating point precision issue. Why won't you transform the expression to a different from, then fit, then inverse transform?
For example:

take `1/model` as the transformation, now you have just a simple polynomial fitting,

```
model_new=(x,a)=1+a*x.^2
```

where you can use `polyfit` and `polyval`, then take `1/result` ...

Comment: Transforming a model like that could potentially be equally dangerous -at least [it can be for exponential fitting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/pitfalls-in-fitting-nonlinear-models-by-transforming-to-linearity.html). One would need to take care and confirm an results by looking at the residuals, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I fit simulated data that looks similar to yours, without scaling:

[image]

The trick is to inspect your data - your signal amplitude is dropping from ~1.5 to ~1.0 between x~40 and ~150. Yet if you inspect the function it's clear that its value should not drop below 1, so it cannot model the data properly.

This data is better fit by including an initial amplitude:

```
model_new = @(a,x) a(1)./(1 + a(2)*x.^2);
```

Looking at the fitting function plotted onto your data it looks like you also include a scaling parameter somewhere.

Including an amplitude parameter improves on the original function, but is not necessarily safe: your data is noisy, and not dropping by much, so you can expect your uncertainties (and correlations) to be large.

Scaling the data before fitting probably would not really help here, since you don't have data down to x=0 and don't know what an appropriate scaling factor should be.